# Is it possible to tether Sony HX60 and run python scripts using pysony?

Tags: sony, tethering, usb

I am trying to use Sony HX60 for my drone and wanted to know if using a Sony HX60 will be a good option as I need to use a USB to control the camera.

Comment: Do you already own the camera?

Comment: No I don't have the camera

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for certain, but it looks unlikely. It does support [MTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol), but probably not the InitiateCapture operation. Although I can't find the operations supported by the HX60, I can find [the operations supported by the HX90V](https://github.com/gphoto/libgphoto2/blob/master/camlibs/ptp2/cameras/sony-hx90v.txt) and that more recent camera from the same line doesn't support tethered capture: just file transfer.